# Как получить все поля на странице?

Tags: javascript

Код, который получается данные с форм:

```
var lenform = document.forms.length;
var buff = '';
for (var i = 0; i < lenform; i++) {
  var len = document.forms[i].elements.length;
  for (var n = 0; n < len; n++) {
    var val = document.forms[i].elements[n].value;
    var name = document.forms[i].elements[n].name;
    var id = document.forms[i].elements[n].id;
    if (val != 0 && val != undefined && val != null) {
      buff += id + ':' + name + ':' + val + '|';
    }
  }
}
```

Как при этом получить все значения value/id/name со всей страницы, а не только формы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
function getAllElements() {
   var elements = [];
   ['input', 'textarea', 'select', 'button'].forEach(function (nodeName) {
       elements.push.apply(elements , document.getElementsByTagName(nodeName));
   });
   return elements;
}

getAllElements().forEach(function (el) {
    console.log(el);
});
```

Comment: код что то не работает. как к примеру просто получить все input c параметром name?

Comment: @shogun, Код работает отлично, вы же просили функцию, которая получит все элементы на странице, это она и есть. Вот пример http://jsfiddle.net/58zH4/

Comment: Код работает отлично.